# How to write a Rails SQL query for finding an object where all children have an equal value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, relational-algebra

I've been reading this, but can't make sense of writing it into a Rails scope :

[find all parent records where all child records have a given value (but not just some child records)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707292/find-all-parent-records-where-all-child-records-have-a-given-value-but-not-just)

I have a `Course`, `Section`, and `Quiz`, object :

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_members
  has_many :members, through: :course_members
  has_many :sections
  has_many :quizzes, through: :sections
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :section
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :quizzes
end
```

I'd like to find all courses of a member, where all quizzes related to that course have the attribute `completed = true`.

So in my `Member` class, I'd ideally like to write something like :

```
has_many :completed_courses, -> { 
   joins(:courses, :quizzes, :sections)
   # .select( 'CASE WHEN quizzes.completed = true then 1 end') ??? maybe ???
}, class_name: 'Course'
```

Haha! But barring that being too complicated. I've been trying to write this simply in the `Course` would also be fine.

Comment: Why `relational-algebra`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, through: :course_members
  has_many :course_members

  has_many :completed_courses,
    -> { joins(:quizzes).where.not(quizzes: {completed: [false, nil]}) },
    through: :course_members,
    source: :course
end
```

*If your `completed` boolean column is `NOT NULL`, then change `[false, nil]` above to just simply `false`*

### Usage Example

```
irb(main):002:0> Member.first.completed_courses
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Course Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "sections" ON "sections"."course_id" = "courses"."id" INNER JOIN "quizzes" ON "quizzes"."section_id" = "sections"."id" INNER JOIN "course_members" ON "courses"."id" = "course_members"."course_id" WHERE (NOT (("quizzes"."completed" = 'f' OR "quizzes"."completed" IS NULL))) AND "course_members"."member_id" = ?  [["member_id", 1]]
```

Comment: That looks like exactly the right answer. Thank you so much. I'm getting the strangest error : `D, [2017-10-24T13:41:08.364579 #5326] DEBUG -- :   Member Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method name' for nil:NilClass` .. but nothing has a `name` attribute..

Comment: No prob! :) Not sure why the `:members` association is being called. Do you have `default_scope` somewhere? Can you try this instead? `has_many :completed_courses, -> { unscoped.joins(:quizzes).where.not(quizzes: {completed: [false, nil]}) }, class_name: 'Course'`

Comment: I was calling it through the Member class. Where were you thinking to put this call?

Comment: Yes, I was under the assumption that you're calling that in the `Member` class. So like, `Member.first.completed_courses`. But the `:members` I was talking about  is `Course has_many :members`, just in case your `Course` class has a `default_scope`. Did it work? If not, can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Ah it does have a default scope.. ha.. that old bug.

Comment: Sorry, the `unscoped` didn't work. I was just affirming that I did have a default_scope for `Course`

Comment: The `unscoped` didn't work? Hmmm, I'll try to replicate this scenario in a few minutes.

Comment: Yah even when I completely remove the `default_scope`, the same error comes up.

Comment: Ohh I see. Hmmm, then the error seems to be strange then; you're right. Is this error generated directly after running `Member.first.completed_courses`?

Comment: Oh actually I think I have encountered this similar `name` error before. Let me see...

Comment: What Rails version is this? As there seems to be some bug in some older version of Rails matched with a specific version of Ruby; from [here](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/380)

Comment: 4.0.13 , ruby 2.1.5

Comment: Sorry nevermind the link above, I was looking at a different repo. I'll try to reproduce this now.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same problem you are having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188400/undefined-method-name-for-nil-when-using-custom-has-many-relationship

Comment: I saw that too. I'll try messing around with Ruby. Thanks so much man!

Comment: No prob! Let me know if you fixed it! :)

Comment: @Trip After reproducing it, I realised that there is a join-table you are using "course_members", and my original answer was wrong all along. Replicating same ruby + rails versions, I managed to now make it work (See updated answer) My apologies.

Comment: Wow I really can't thank you enough. I really appreciate your help brother!! Thank you so much. If it weren't against site rules, I'd DDOS upvote you. :D

Comment: @Trip haha no worries! I'm glad I could help! :)