# FetchXml: get only records for which all related records satisfy the condition

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

Dynamics 365 v8.2. FetchXml.

Each `isv_entity1` record can be linked with one or more `isv_entity2` records (one to many). I need to get **only** `isv_entity1` records for which **all** linked `isv_entity2` records correspond some condition. If at least one linked `isv_entity2` record does not meet the condition, then the `isv_entity1` record should not fall into the selection.

How can I do it via FetchXml?

If I will use this query:

```
<fetch distinct='true' >
  <entity name='isv_entity1' >
    <attribute name='isv_entity1id' />    
    <link-entity name='isv_entity2' from='isv_entity2id' to='isv_entity2id' >
      <filter type='and' >
          <condition attribute='isv_someProp' operator='eq' value='someValue' />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

then I get the `isv_entity1` records which have *at least one* linked `isv_entity2` corresponds the condition. But it is not the same what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is: [find all parent records where all child records have a given value (but not just some child records)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23707292)

The above is sql equivalent of your requirement, unfortunately sub-queries are not supported in FetchXML.

So either you have to use two queries or to query all the records and iterate to verify/filter the results that match your criteria

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** instead of linking to other questions. If you think that this question is a duplicate of the other, please flag it as such

Comment: @NicoHaase that’s what I written in two statements in answer